# cors problem with react js request and jwt

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, cors, preflight

i'm trying to fetch data with react from asp.net core 3.1 so i login with a request and get the jwt token. after that i want to send a request for getting data from api but it cause "preflight request "Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44328/Address' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
apiAddress.js:24 GET https://localhost:44328/Address net::ERR_FAILED", i work with visual studio localhost as api server and configured startup like below:

```
     //in ConfigureServices
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: AllowedOrigins,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder
                                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                                        .SetIsOriginAllowed(hostName => true);

                              });
        });
//in configure
    app.UseCors(AllowedOrigins);
```

my fetch request is like below in reactjs:

```
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        'method': 'GET',
        'mode': 'cors',
        'credentials': 'include',
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
            //'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization':`bearer ${token}`
        }
    });
```

and finally my controller is like below:

```
[ApiController, EnableCors("AllowedOrigins"), Authorize,  Route("[controller]")]
public class AddressController : ControllerBase
```

what is wrong, i must mention other actions without [Authorize] attribute working ok, but action with it not works?!
some one mentioned that i should enable options in iis, but didn't explained how?

Comment: your URL is in the proxy in `package.json`, or you write it as a string in the ajax post?

Comment: `'Authorization':`bearer ${token}`` This triggers CORS preflight. The headers and values we can use without triggering CORS are very specific.(`Authorization` is not one of them)

Comment: i wrote it as string in variable

Comment: so what should i do

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to enable CORS on IIS. Here are steps how to do.

1. Open Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager.
2. Right click the site you want to enable CORS for and go to Properties.
3. Change to the HTTP Headers tab.
4. In the Custom HTTP headers section, click Add.
5. Enter Access-Control-Allow-Origin as the header name.
6. Enter * as the header value.
7. Click Ok twice.

Comment: i'm working with local host and other actions working fine except the one with authorize filter, is this make any difference in your answer? thk

Comment: Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44328/Address' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
apiAddress.js:24 GET https://localhost:44328/Address net::ERR_FAILED

Answer (score 0):

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: ....

> other actions without [Authorize] attribute working ok, but action with it not works

In [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference#cors-preflight-request), you would find:

*A CORS preflight request is used to determine whether the resource being requested is set to be shared across origins by the server. And The OPTIONS requests are always anonymous, server would not correctly respond to the preflight request if anonymous authentification is not enabled.*

While hosting on IIS server, you can try to install the [IIS CORS module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module) and configure for the site/application to make it work well.

Besides, if you'd like to make it work on local with IIS express, for testing purpose on CORS, you can try to allow anonymous access.

Or run it with kestrel and write custom middleware to correctly respond to the preflight request.